# var col = new jsColor("red"); produces error condition

Tags: javascript, html, jscolor

I am doing development on Windows 7 using jboss.  I have placed jsColor.js in the same directory as my index.html file which is in html5.  I have a test function in a separate .js file.  I have included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor.js"></script>
```

in the header of index.html.

The test function is as follows.

```
function Test(){
    alert("Before call");
    var col = new jsColor("red");
    alert("After call");
}
```

The unmodified function gives me only one alert box "Before call".  However commenting out

```
    var col = new jsColor("red");
```

gives me two alert boxes: "Before call" and "After call".

This suggests that

```
    var col = new jsColor("red");
```

produces an error.

Comment: Open JavaScript console and check the error message ...

Comment: and are you including your other js file in your html file after `jscolor.js` is being included?